# Text area with 'CSS like' Properties and Values Auto Suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete, multiautocompletetextview

I need MultiAutoComplete functionality in text area
I tried datalist, jquery autocomplete but none of them seems to be working with my requirement

Can anyone help me out please ?

In text area

````
 ```if I need suggestion in Property```

 e.g fever [this Should be searched with autocomplete suggestion 
 then 
 fever : [ all values of fever with autocomplete suggestions ]
           Very High
           High
           Normal

 Then in the same text area / div, other Properties with their corresponding values.
````

Thank you

Comment: This should be handled in backend. I don't think any autocomplete library will provide you this kind of feature. You should have a database and develop an API, which will result in other same types. All the libraries will look for spells

Comment: This is only handful if you have certain amount of search text and its suggestions. So that you can declare a object, which contains all the data.